# How to ignore the dependencies of a specific package when installing it with pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

Is there a possibility to install a python package with pipenv without also installing the dependencies?

I'm looking for an analogue of `pip install package_name --no-dependencies` for the `Pipfile`. I already tried to specify with a marker but it raises an exception.

```
[packages]
"psycopg2-binary" = "*"
"aiopg"={version = "*", markers="--no-dependencies"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `pipenv` does not support this. One workaround adds a `script` like the following to the end of `Pipfile`:

```
[scripts]
install  = "sh -c 'pipenv install ; pip install --no-deps aiopg'"
```

With this script, calling `pipenv run install` installs all dependencies from the `[packages]` section, including `aiopg` but excluding its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure pipenv supports that*, but I think the following option may work (never tried it):

1. Install via pip into a requirements.txt file

   `pip install <package> --no-deps -r requirements.txt` --> then import to pipenv `pipenv install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`
2. If you already have a Pipfile in your current project, export your current pipenv file to a requirements.txt file

   `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt`
3. Combine the two files and then pipenv install from the combined requirements.txt file

   `pipenv install -r path/to/requirements.txt`

Perhaps this [link](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#editable-dependencies-e-g-e) from the docs may help as well