# Pipenv ignore sub-dependency

Tags: python, pipenv

Using Pipenv, how do I prevent `pipenv install` from installing certain sub-dependencies (dependencies of dependencies)?

Specifically, I want to install the *tensorflow* pacakge as a dependency of my pacakge, but I *don't* want to install the *tensorboard* package, which is a dependency of *tensorflow* even though it's not really needed.

I can kind of work around the problem by removing the *tensorboard* package after installation, but that does not remove all the packages that *tensorboard* package pulled in as dependencies (like *werkzeug*).

A more complete but complex solution would be to look at `pipenv graph` to figure out which dependencies only appear under *tensorboard* (and are not needed by anything else), but maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: With `pip`, you can use `--no-deps` to specify that you don't want to install subdependencies. I'm a bit puzzled that this flag is not available with `pipenv`.

Comment: `--no-deps` applies to dependencies, not sub-dependencies, right? And in any case, it applies to all dependencies, and you can't ignore a specific one, right?

Comment: Depends how you define it. If your package depends on tensorflow, which depends on tensorboard, then tensorboard is a subdependency of your package :) And yes, `--no-deps` applies to all of them, not a specific one, but you could add all of them exept tensorboard as deps to your package.

Comment: Right. But then we are back to parsing the depdendency tree as I suggested as a workaround so that I get the list of "actual" dependencies, which is a bit of a pain. Hence the question in the first place.

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: [How to ignore the dependencies of a specific package when installing it with pipenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51046150/2745495). Also has no answer though :|

Answer (score 4):

Currently, `pipenv` does not support this. There are a couple of workarounds (as you have alluded to):

1. Add the following `script` to `Pipfile`, and then run `pipenv run pip-install`:

   ```
   [scripts]
   # requirements.txt identifies the package to install w/o deps, e.g. tensorflow
   pip-install  = "pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt"
   ```

***OR***
2. Set `PIP_NO_DEPS=1` in `.env`, and then call `pip` explicitly to install the parent package:

```sh
pipenv run pip install tensorflow
```

With each of these cases, you'll still need to add the required dependencies to `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock`; [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) can be useful for this:

```sh
# note: jq must be installed using the system package manager
pipenv install "pipdeptree"

pipdeptree --json-tree |  # format the dependency tree as JSON
  jq '.[] | select(.key == "tensorflow") |  # filter to the target package
    .dependencies[] | select( .key != "tensorboard" ) |  # select all deps except tensorboard
    "\( .key )\( .required_version )"' |  # and output the req to install with pipenv
  xargs pipenv install
```

A third option is to fork `tensorflow`, remove the `tensorboard` dependency, and `pip install git+https://github.com/the-fork-of/tensorflow.git`.